# My Archlinux makes buzz sound when my second VGA monitor is on and HDMI is also plugged

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio

I have 2 same monitor Dell from 2010, one primary as DVI and the second connected via VGA.

When I put *twinvew* with [xrandr](/questions/tagged/xrandr), the secondary monitor start to makes buzz noise.

**Is there a workaround ?**

System hardware :

```
description: Desktop Computer
product: System Product Name (SKU)
vendor: System manufacturer
version: System Version
serial: System Serial Number
width: 4294967295 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32

description: Motherboard
product: H170M-PLUS
vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
physical id: 0
version: Rev X.0x
```

Default integrated Intel sound card :

```
description: Audio device
product: Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
version: 31
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
resources: irq:124 memory:f7040000-f7043fff memory:f7020000-f702ffff
```

### Edit

On the secondary monitor, I have both the VGA wire and a HDMI wire (for TV when switching for analogical (archlinux) to numeric(TV)).

**If I unplug HDMI on secondary monitor (TV), no more buzzing**

Comment: What do you mean by "the system start to makes buzz noise"? What is "the system" precisely? Do you dual boot? Can you observe the same in another OS?

Comment: The sound is _genetated_ by the monitor. I don't have dual boot. Have you seen my edit about both HDMI and VGA wire on secondary monitor ?

Comment: Have you tried on another OS or computer all together?